# Is it always necessary to check isTruncated in S3 ListObjects / ListObjectsV2 responses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

S3's `ListObjects` and `ListObjectsV2` API responses both include an `IsTruncated` response element, which (according to the [V1 API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html))

> Specifies whether (`true`) or not (`false`) all of the results were returned. If the number of results exceeds that specified by `MaxKeys`, all of the results might not be returned.

According to the [*Listing Objects Keys*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html#ListingKeysPaginated) section of the S3 documentation:

> As buckets can contain a virtually unlimited number of keys, the complete results of a list query can be extremely large. To manage large result sets, the Amazon S3 API supports pagination to split them into multiple responses. Each list keys response returns a page of up to 1,000 keys with an indicator indicating if the response is truncated. You send a series of list keys requests until you have received all the keys. AWS SDK wrapper libraries provide the same pagination.

Clearly we need to check `isTruncated` if there's a possibility that the listing could match more than 1000 keys. Similarly, if we explicitly set `MaxKeys` then we definitely need to check `isTruncated` if there's ever the possibility that a listing could match more than `MaxKeys` keys.

However, do we need to check `isTruncated` if we never expect there to be more than `min(1000, MaxKeys)` matching keys?

I think that the weakest possible interpretation of the S3 API docs is that S3 will return *at most* `min(1000, MaxKeys)` keys per listing call but technically can return fewer keys *even if more matching keys exist and would fit in the response*. For example, if there are 10 matchings keys and `MaxKeys == 1000` then it would be technically valid for S3 to return, say, 3 keys in the first API response and 7 in the second. (Technically I suppose it could even return zero keys and set `isTruncated = true`, but that behavior seems unlikely).

With these weak semantics I think we ***always*** need to check `isTruncated`, even if we're listing what we expect to be a very small number of keys. As a corollary, any code which *doesn't* check `isTruncated` is (most likely) buggy.

In the past, I've observed this listing semantic from other AWS APIs (including the EC2 Reserved Instance Marketplace API).

**Is this a correct interpretation of the S3 API semantics?** Or does S3 actually guarantee (but not document) stronger semantics (e.g. "if more than `MaxKeys` keys match the listing then the listing will contain exactly `MaxKeys`)?

I'm especially interested in answers which cite official AWS sources (such as AWS forum responses, SDK issues, etc).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it will always return the maximum number of values, which is as you state it: `min(1000, MaxKeys)`

So, if you know you will always have under 1000 results, you would not need to check `isTruncated`.

Mind you, it's fairly easy to construct a `while` loop to do so. (Probably easier than writing this question!)

Comment: Hi John: thanks for your reply, but it doesn't exactly answer my question: I know how to write pagination code and I know that S3 _typically_ returns the maximum number of values, but I don't know that this this is definitively _guaranteed_ by the API. I'm interested in knowing whether there are any edge-cases where this typical -case behavior might *not* hold (e.g. during re-sharding of S3's internal metadata).